# terminal cant do ls or cd

Tags: macos, terminal, ls, cd

Can anybody explain what is wrong with my terminal:

```
 
$ echo $PATH
=/usr/local/bin
$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
$ cd
-bash: find: command not found
```

Why won't these commands work? Help? Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` has a line that looks like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

This is overwriting all the existing stuff that needs to be in your `$PATH`. You need to change this line to look like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: how do i do this from a non functional terminal? where is the .bash_profile or .bashrc file located?

Comment: @VincentWarmerdam: What command-line editor do you like to use? You can always use the full path to commands, e.g. `/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile`. And these files live in your home dir.

Answer (score 1):

"`ls`" lives in "`/bin`" and "`find`" lives in "`/usr/bin`".  You need to add these to your $PATH in your bash_profile or .bashrc.

Comment: how do i do this from a non functional terminal? where are the bash_profile or bashrc files located?

Comment: type in "`cd ~`" to get to your home directory in terminal.app and then type in "`open .bashrc`" and "`open .bash_profile`" and that should open the files into TextEdit.

Comment: cant use cd ... 
```
Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentwarmerdam$ cd ~
-bash: find: command not found 
```